# Regex - Match multiple times in a string

Tags: c#, regex, rosalind

I am trying to do a regex search on 'NNTSY` so that I can get two matches.

- NNTS
- NTSY

When I attempted to match using the pattern `?<NGrlyosylation>N[^P][ST][^P])"`, I am only getting one match, which is `NNTS`.

How can I use Regex to match `NNTSY` so that two matches can be found?

*NOTE*: Background info: Rosalind problem can be found [here](http://rosalind.info/problems/mprt/).

Here is my code.

```
        input = "NNTSY";
        Regex regex = new Regex("(?<NGrlyosylation>N[^P][ST][^P])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            // Need to add 1 to because match index is 0 based
            const int offset = 1;
            yield return match.Index + offset;
        }
```

Comment: you are trying to find overlapping matches

Comment: @rock321987 Yes. Exactly.

Comment: For those who want the full source, check out the source here => https://github.com/dance2die/Demo.Rosalind/blob/master/Demo.Rosalind/Demo.Rosalind.Tests/MPRT/MprtTest.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding overlapping matches is usually not allowed in most programming languages (except few).
So, I don't think there exists a pure regex way to solve this, but you can use `Substring` in C# with `lookahead` as

```
(?=N[^P][ST][^P]).
```

*C# Code*

```
string input = "NNTSY";
Regex regex = new Regex("(?=N[^P][ST][^P]).", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match match = regex.Match(input);

while (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(match.Index, 4));
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/KiSfGe)**

Comment: Thanks @rock321987. I wasn't aware of Regex `lookahead` concept so I was lost. At least the tests I created passes all cases and I am ready to move on.

Comment: @Sung glad, it helped..`lookaheads` are zero width-assertion..it means that they do not consume any character..the regex will be checked against the string without the matched string being consumed

Comment: @Sung `.` was not required in the regex..simple lookahead will suffice here..adding `.` will speed up the process a bit